# Inherit Sitecore renderings from another item (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore8

I have a portion of our website with a deep IA.  At the top is a page that will have a number of components added to its right rail.  A good majority of the child pages under that top page will  have the same right rail components and thus I've been tasked with looking at inheriting the renderings from that page.  More generically, I'm trying to write a function that does the following pseudocode:

```
If using inheritance {
Get Renderings from given placeholder on an item
Add those renderings to a placeholder on the fly at run-time
} else {
  render out components as normal
}
```

Note, that I do not want to persist them to the data store, I just want them added on the fly because if someone actually adds renderings to the current item, the inheritance stops for this item.  Or, if someone changes renderings at the top, that should propogate down to the children as well.

I have some code that gets me rendering references from a given placeholder (lifted from Stack Overflow):

```
var renderingReferences = inheritFrom.Visualization.GetRenderings(Sitecore.Context.Device, true);
var renderingsInPlaceholder = renderingReferences.Where(r => r.Placeholder.EndsWith('/' + placeholder, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

However, I'm having some trouble finding out how to add the renderingReference items to the placeholder on the child page.  I've seen some code that deals with devices:

```
var layoutField = new LayoutField(item.Fields[Sitecore.FieldIDs.LayoutField]);
var layoutDefinition = LayoutDefinition.Parse(layoutField.Value);
var deviceDefinition = layoutDefinition.GetDevice(Sitecore.Context.Device.ID.ToString());

foreach (var reference in references)
{
    var renderingDefinition = new RenderingDefinition
    {
        ItemID = reference.RenderingItem.ID.ToString(),
        Placeholder = placeHolder,
        Datasource = reference.RenderingItem.DataSource
    };

    deviceDefinition.AddRendering(renderingDefinition);
}
```

But this didn't seem to work...any help you can provide would be appreciated...

Comment: Have you taken a look at this [Sitecore Placeholder Fallback blog post](http://www.hhogdev.com/blog/2015/september/sitecore-placeholder-fallback.aspx)?

Comment: Funny you mention that, I found it this morning, and I'm trying to see if it has everything I need to take care of my task.

Comment: jammykam, if you want the points, you can post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as such.  I've gotten it working with the link you had posted, though it took some messing with it to get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are essentially looking for Placeholder fallback to allow you to use the components specified in the same placeholder of the parent item. You can find more details on how to achieve this including the required code in this [Sitecore Placeholder Fallback blog post](http://www.hhogdev.com/blog/2015/september/sitecore-placeholder-fallback.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. When I'm done I need to write a blog post about my trials and tribulations with this method.

Comment: Please do, it will be useful for us all